# Can Spring.NET AOP be used with Unity container?

Tags: .net, unity-container, aop, spring.net

It is possible to use Spring.NET's aspect-oriented capabilities without using the Spring DI container? Specifically, in an app that uses Unity for IoC/DI, will Spring's AOP work?

I'm reading through http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html but it's quite dense and not clear to me if it requires the Spring container to be managing all objects in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

Today it's not possible. Spring.Aop interact with Spring.Core and have a huge dependency of Spring.Core, the container itself.

To use AOP with Unity, you need to search about Policy Injection.

Policy Injection produces same concepts, but is limited regarding Spring.Aop.